# How to locate position of number in power 3 pyramid diagram

Tags: list-manipulation

I need to populate a power 3 pyramid diagram display numbers, of 10 levels, starting from 1.
Each number will be pointing to 3 numbers under the next level.
Each level will contain different total slots count, in formula of  3^(Level count-1)

[image]

My question is:

1. How can I calculate slot number of each row?
   Eg: Level 2 slot number is 2,3,4.
   Eg: Level 3 is 5 to 13. 
   Eg: Level 4 is 14 to 40.
2. How can I know which is the immediate upper level referring slot number?
   Eg: Slot number 5 upper level is 2
   Eg: Slot number 25 upper level is 8
   Eg: Slot number 3 upper level is 1
3. How can I know which 3 slot numbers are the immediate lower level slot number?
   Eg: Slot number 2 lower levels are 5,6,7
   Eg: Slot number 13 lower levels are 28,39,40
4. Is it possible to track up to 10 upper level trail of a slot number?
   Eg: Slot number 20 upper level trails are 7,2,1
   Eg: Slot number 34 upper level trails are 11,4,1
5. Is it possible to track up to 10 lower level trail of a slot number?
   Eg: Slot number 1 lower levels are 1 to 40,...
   Eg: Slot number 3 lower levels are 8,9,10,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,...
   Eg: Slot number 12 lower levels are 35,36,37,...

Comment: is this a mathematica question?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Are you sure you are posting on the right site? There is nothing in your question making it clear that it is concerned with Mathematica software.

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE! First take the [tour] so you learn the basic rules of the site. Your question may be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) because it seems to be [off-topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), i.e. its not about Wolfram Mathematica programing. If that's not your intenetion, please [edit] your question to make it explicitly about Mathematica programming. Include a [formatted](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) minimum example of the code you are working on.

Comment: Since the user hasn't indicated anything so far... oh well.

Answer (score 2):

I think `Association` is the right way to approach this problem.

Firstly, generate the numbers and `Partition` them length-wise {$1$,$3$,$3^2$,$3^3$...} using `` Internal`ParitionRagged ``. For `nlevel=4`, we get,

```
 list[nLevel_] := Internal`PartitionRagged[Range[Total[3^#]], 3^#] &@ Range[0, nLevel - 1];
 list[4]
```

> {{1}, {2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13}, {14, 15, 16, 17, 18,
>      19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35,
>      36, 37, 38, 39, 40}}

Secondly, `Partition` each element of the above list by 3 and relate the corresponding partition to the above element using a `Rule`.

```
pyramid = list[4];
f[x_, y_] := Rule @@@ Transpose[{y, Partition[x, 3]}]
f[pyramid[[4]], pyramid[[3]]]
```

> {5 -> {14, 15, 16}, 6 -> {17, 18, 19}, 7 -> {20, 21, 22}, 
>    8 -> {23, 24, 25}, 9 -> {26, 27, 28}, 10 -> {29, 30, 31}, 
>    11 -> {32, 33, 34}, 12 -> {35, 36, 37}, 13 -> {38, 39, 40}}

Now, using `Fold` we recursively convert every `List` into an `Association`

```
pyramidTree = Fold[f, First@#, Rest@#] &@Reverse[pyramid];
asscPyramid = Replace[pyramidTree, List -> Association, All, Heads -> True]
```

> <|1 -> <|2 -> <|5 -> Association[14, 15, 16], 
>        6 -> Association[17, 18, 19], 7 -> Association[20, 21, 22]|>, 
>      3 -> <|8 -> Association[23, 24, 25], 9 -> Association[26, 27, 28], 
>        10 -> Association[29, 30, 31]|>, 
>      4 -> <|11 -> Association[32, 33, 34], 
>        12 -> Association[35, 36, 37], 13 -> Association[38, 39, 40]|>|>|

**OP's questions**

1. To get the slot numbers of a particular level, simply access the elements of the pyramid. For level 2 slot numbers: `pyramid[[2]]`.
2. To get the immediate slot number of a particular element, use `Position`.

   ```
   getPosition[n_] := (Quiet@Position[asscPyramid, x_ /; MemberQ[Keys[x], n]]) /. 
   Key[m_] :> m // Flatten
   getPosition[5]//Last
   (*2*)
   ```
3. For this, you can find the position and extract it from the association. To get the elements of slot 13: `(asscPyramid @@ getPosition[13])[13]`.
4. `getPosition` exactly does this.
5. Same as Q3. To get it in a `List` format.

   ```
   ((asscPyramid @@ getPosition[3])[3] /. {Association -> List}) /.
   {Rule[x_, y_] -> {x, y}} // Flatten
   (*{8, 23, 24, 25, 9, 26, 27, 28, 10, 29, 30, 31}*)
   ```